# Laravel Sanctum for SPA and Mobile authentication

Tags: laravel

I have an existing Laravel project which is using Laravel Sanctum to authenticate client request for a React project.

The approach used is [SPA](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#spa-authentication) (client and server share same top-level domain, no token needed).

I need to create a mobile application and i was reading [Mobile Application Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#mobile-application-authentication) documentation from Laravel.

What would be the best approach to have my API working for both client and mobile app requests?

Comment: hi, Have you figured out how to do this please?